# Top 5 list repeating values?

Tags: list, google-sheets, formula, repeat

I tried to copy someones formula for making a top 5 list and I did my best to switch out values with the ones that correspond with my list. Why is it repeating values?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Did you press enter when calculating when finishing your formula or CTRL+SHFT+ENTER?

Comment: I Just pressed enter, why?

Comment: Using CSE will turn it into an array formula,  I am not familiar with your formula but sometimes it can make a difference.  You will know you did it right if excel places { } around your formula.  You cannot add them manually

Comment: I tried what you said and it results in this: =ArrayFormula(INDEX(A2:A901,MATCH(1,INDEX((H2:H901=LARGE(H2:H901,ROWS(D$1:D1)))*(COUNTIF(D$1:D1,A2:A901)=0),),0)))   No change to the outcomes

Comment: @ForwardEd FYI this question is tagged Excel but it is about Google Docs. Interface and array formula formatting indicate that.

Comment: @MarkBalhoff I was beginning to wonder about something along those lines or web based excel.  pic did not look familiar for app.

Comment: Noted and changed tags, do you guys know of a formula i could use to make a top 5 list instead of the one im using? pretty new to this stuff this list is a hobby of my girlfriend and I

Comment: Top 5 is based on which column????

Answer (score 0):

[`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343) is possible way to find top N rows:

```
=QUERY({A:B},"select Col1, sum(Col2) group by Col1 order by sum(Col2) desc limit 5")`
```

[image]